# Holonomy group as a quotient group of $\text{GL}(k,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, holonomy

Currently, I'm reading the script of a Global Analysis lecture at my university.

There, we look at a real vector-bundle $(E,\pi,M)$ of rank $k$ with a given connection $\nabla$ and define the *holonomy group* at the point $p\in M$ as
$$\text{Hol}_p(\nabla):=\{P_\gamma:\gamma\text{ is a closed curve with basis }p\}.$$
Here, $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow M$ is continuous with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(1)=p$ and $P_\gamma$ is the unique parallel transport along $\gamma$.

We have shown beforehand that $P_\gamma$ is an isomorphism and that there is a certain mulitplicative action, i.e. $P_{\gamma\gamma\prime}=P_\gamma\circ P_{\gamma\prime}$.

Hence, $\text{Hol}_p(\nabla)$ can be looked at as a subgroup of $\text{GL}(k,\mathbb{R})$.

And suddenly, my problem appears: We set $G:=\text{GL}(k,\mathbb{R})/$~, call this the *holonomy group of $E$ w.r.t. $\nabla$* and state $\text{Hol}_p(\nabla)\cong G$.

But what's the equivalence relation? I thought fruitlessly, and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomy) doesn't state it this way.

Comment: That just seems wrong to me. The holonomy group is a subgroup, not a quotient.